# I would like to know how to iterate through df.column3 find match in df.column2 and add name of df.column1 based on matches to a new column df.column4

Tags: python, pandas

Test data looks like:

`Column1 Column2 Column3
johnny  100     900
matty   300     100
grapy   400     300
snapp   500     300`

Expected Result:

`Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
johnny  100     900     None
matty   300     100     johnny
grapy   400     300     matty
snapp   500     300     matty`

Attempted to run """df['Column1'][df['Column2'].isin(df['Column3'])"""
This partly worked but failed on some of the items that didnt match
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't work properly, its because you have duplicate values:

```
df['Column4'] = df.Column2.map(dict(zip(df.Column3, df.Column1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using a dictionnary of possible values :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['matty', 300, 900], ['grapy', 400, 300], ['snapp', 500, 300]], columns=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])
df = df.set_index('Column2')

dic = df['Column1'].to_dict()
df['Column4'] = [dic[n] if n in dic.keys() else None for n in df['Column3']]
df = df.reset_index()

df
Out[114]: 
   Column2 Column1  Column3 Column4
0      300   matty      900    None
1      400   grapy      300   matty
2      500   snapp      300   matty
```